# laravel in subdirectory but route points to parent directory

Tags: laravel, routes, lighttpd, subdirectory

i have a problem in laravel route i don't know how to fix it!

well first of all i should say my webserver is lighttpd and there's no way to change it to nginx or apache if you want to say use another webserver... :D

well, my project was in "/path/to/some-where/htdocs" and my domain was "example.com"

and in "lighttpd.conf" i pointed "example.com" to "/path/to/some-where/htdocs/public/" and everything worked well and laravel worked fine, but because of some reasons i made some changes cause we needed "example.com" domain for some other projects

i moved project to "foo" subdirectory so now my project path is "/path/to/some-where/htdocs/foo/" and also i made some changes in lighttpd and pointed "example.com/foo" to "/path/to/some-where/htdocs/foo/public/"

also i changed APP_URI in .env to "http://example.com/foo" 
but when i open "example.com/foo" it shows me "route not found" error, laravel it's working but it doesn't recognize "/foo" as base directory and when i put all of routes in a route group with "foo" prefix it works fine!

for testing i made these routes

```
    Route::get("/", function(}{return "sweet home!";));
    Route::get("/{slug}", function($slug}{return $slug;));
```

when i open "example.com/foo" it should show me "sweet home" but instead, it shows me "foo" cause as i said laravel doesn't recognize "foo" as base directory 
it seems i should change base directory or base uri of project but i couldn't find anything

as i said i changed APP_URI, and also i put

```
    RewriteBase /foo/
```

in .htacess but no result!

Comment: i forgot to say i also removed vendor directory and ran "composer update" command and also "php artisan cache:clear", "php artisan config:clear" and "composer dump-autoload".

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix your routes this way :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function() {
   Route::get("/", function(}{return "sweet home!";));
   Route::get("/{slug}", function($slug}{return $slug;));
});
```

Comment: well it works in that way, but as i said, project in physically in "foo", so i think correct way is changing base uri of project instead adding prefix

and also there's an issue in this solution, ulr() function would return "example.com" !

Comment: You can write your own url helper method to generate these urls, or use named routes. you can also override the url() method if you used it a lot in your project